# 301 redierction, matching urls through regex. Matching dashes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match urls for a migration, however I can't seem to have a regex which matches it.

I've tried different expressions and using regex checkers to determine where exactly it's broken, but it's not clear to me

This is my regex

```
https:\/\/blog\.xyz\.ca\/EN\/post\/201[0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/*\).aspx
```

I'm trying to match these kinds of urls (hundreds)

https://blog.xyz.ca/EN/post/2019/05/14/how-test-higher-education-test-can-test-more-test-students-and-test-sdf-the-test.aspx

https://blog.xyz.ca/EN/post/2019/05/14/how-test.aspx

https://blog.xyz.ca/EN/post/2019/05/14/how-test-higher-the-test.aspx

And remap them to something like this

https://blog.xyz.ca/2017/12/21/test-how-the-testaspx

I thought that I could match the dash section using the wildcard, but it seems to not be working and none of the generators are giving me a clear warning. I've tried https://regexr.com/ and https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: As Emma said, it looks you just need to remove `EN/post/` from your URLs. If not, please add more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, here we might just want to have a simple expression and capture our desired URL components, according to which we would find our redirect rules, and we can likely start with:

```
(.+\.ca)\/EN\/post(\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})(\/.+)\.aspx
```

and if necessary, we would be adding/reducing our constraints, and I'm guessing that no validation might be required.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NC920q/1/)

or:

```
(.+\.ca)\/EN\/post(\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})(\/.+)(\.aspx)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FaxZzy/1/)